# How to structure a Swift package(SPM)containing multiple packages(libraries/targets) and version them

Tags: ios, swift, monorepo, swift-package-manager

I would live to have a GitHub repo containing multiple swift packages.

How would that need to be structured? do I need multiple Package.swift? or one with multiple libraries and target?

The last one is what I have been suggested so far, but feel free to tell me more. I am quite new to swift environment.

So far I am trying:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.7
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "newskit-themes",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "newskit",
            targets: ["newskit"]
        ),
        .library(
            name: "the-sun",
            targets: ["the-sun"]
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "newskit"
        ),
        .target(
            name: "the-sun"
        )
    ]
)
```

The problem is.. I need to version each target/library/subpackage; in this case 'newskit' and 'the-sun'.
How can I achieve that?  what is the right structure of the monorepo?
Folders, files, and the Package.swift should look like to version each of those.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the more specific meaning of "Structure" that you mentioned? If you want to specify versions for two libraries separately, you need two packages. If not, you can set up two targets in the same package, just like what you're doing now.

Comment: With structure I mean, folders,  files and anything I need to write to achieve multiple packages and version them.

So if you could provide me an example of the structure of the monorepo repo, that would help me. This still leaves me confused on how to achieve it